# Mongodb - aggregate function nested ob

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

We need to calculate the minimum bounding rectangle (MBR) on Geospatial data.
In oracle, we  have `SDO_AGGR_MBR` function, is there any similar function in MongoDB.

```
"coord" : {
    "type" : "Polygon",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        [ 
            [ 
                25.5377574375611, 
                42.8545750237221
            ], 
            [ 
                47.7803203666229, 
                42.8545750237221
            ], 
            [ 
                47.7803203661319, 
                52.0987759993153
            ], 
            [ 
                25.5377574370701, 
                52.0987759993153
            ], 
            [ 
                25.5377574375611, 
                42.8545750237221
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

We have the geometry data like above but the coordinates length may vary. So, we need to find the `minx`, `miny`, `maxx` and `maxy` from these data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in function for it. But you can simply do the following;

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$coordinates"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$coordinates"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      minX: {
        $min: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$coordinates", 0 ] }
      },
      maxX: {
        $max: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$coordinates", 0 ] }
      },
      minY: {
        $min: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$coordinates", 1 ] }
      },
      maxY: {
        $max: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$coordinates", 1 ] }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Where first unwraps the `coordinates` array with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) (twice for extra `[ ]` block), so that `aggregate pipeline` can iterate on it. Then we just use a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with `_id: null` which is [a special operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-null) to evaluate min/max values for all elements of the array.

which will get you a response you request;

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "maxX": 47.7803203666229,
    "maxY": 52.0987759993153,
    "minX": 25.5377574370701,
    "minY": 42.8545750237221
  }
]
```

check on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kbvCiV778dL)

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/BkYccPpt6OM
Seems, it is not giving correct result.

Comment: @user3474541 there were two issues, (1) your input json had problem with second & third `coordinates` where it had one extra `[ ]` block, (2) you need some identifier to distinguish between the blocks of separate `coordinates` containing objects. Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WaP7QXVw_Vx), hope that will help!

Comment: Noted. But the thing is it gives result for each block/object and we have requirement to check this on entire objects.

Comment: @user3474541 oh so you'd like to merge them all into a single result? Then just fixing the `[ ]` trouble in your example should be enough, make `_id: null` again in `$group` for that! Like [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b8iqjt39tav). I was a bit too overzealous, my original answer was OK :)

Comment: It's working when removed [ ]  from the data. But these brackets added by java client ( when om.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon converted to string)

Comment: @user3474541 can you check the updated answer? Doing `$unwind` twice works perfectly... Also [your second example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gran3Xpcp8m)

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to employ the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) operators along with [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/). This allows you to process each document by manipulating the array's *inline* and then use [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operators to obtain the bounding values:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$replaceRoot": {  
    "newRoot": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "m": {
            "$map": {
              "input": {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": "$coord.coordinates",
                  "initialValue": [],
                  "in": {
                    "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this"]
                  }
                }
              },
              "in": {
                "x": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$this", 0 ] },
                "y": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$this", 1 ] }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "coord": "$coord",
          "minX": { "$min": "$$m.x" },
          "minY": { "$min": "$$m.y" },
          "maxX": { "$max": "$$m.x" },
          "maxY": { "$max": "$$m.y" }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

And the output, would be like:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d9330e95994eb7018f59218"),
        "coord" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                        [
                                [
                                        25.5377574375611,
                                        42.8545750237221
                                ],
                                [
                                        47.7803203666229,
                                        42.8545750237221
                                ],
                                [
                                        47.7803203661319,
                                        52.0987759993153
                                ],
                                [
                                        25.5377574370701,
                                        52.0987759993153
                                ],
                                [
                                        25.5377574375611,
                                        42.8545750237221
                                ]
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "minX" : 25.5377574370701,
        "minY" : 42.8545750237221,
        "maxX" : 47.7803203666229,
        "maxY" : 52.0987759993153
}
```

Note the usage of the [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) aggregation pipeline stage, as this will allow the nested expressions with [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) to essentially provide *global variables* to the document to produce that can be utilized in any output property.

The [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) here basically serves the function to *flatten* the array from the standard GeoJSON form into just an array of coordinate pairs, without the additional bounding array.

This then feeds input to the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) which employs [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) in order to *re-map* each coordinate pair into an *object* with `x` and `y` keys. This makes things much more simple for the actual execution or *output* section of the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/).

> **Note**: An alternate approach to using [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) against each key within the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) might well be to use [`$zip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) and [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/):
>
> ```
>    "in": {
>         "$arrayToObject": { "$zip": { "inputs": [ ["x","y"], "$$this" ] } }
>    }
> ```
>
> It has the same principle in the overall output, but takes advantage of [`$zip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) producing "paired" arrays, which also happens to be valid input for [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to produce the final *object* form.

In the final part, we now basically have an *array of objects* with the named keys `x` and `y`. MongoDB allows a convenient way to *remap* simply the values for those named keys with notation like `"$$m.x"` where the `"$$m` expression related to the named variable of the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) and is our *array of objects*, and the `.x` part of course simply means ***only the values of `x`***. This is a basic shorthand for a [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) statement in itself, which suits this special usage case.

These arrays of values for specific properties can now be applied to the [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operators, and this is how you get you `min` and `max` coordinates for a bounding rectangle.

---

**Note that *inline operators* for arrays should always be preferred to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).**

The [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) aggregation pipeline stage was an old introductory way of dealing with array elements by essentially *flattening* them into separate documents.

Though necessary when you actually want to *group* on a value as a key that comes from within an array, most operations which don't actually need that ( like this one ) can be done with more modern approaches.

The usage of [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is actually a **huge** performance penalty, due to it's function essentially being to replicate the entire parent document content of the field containing the array into it's own new document. Particularly in large datasets this has a very negative effect on performance, due to much increases I/O and memory usage.

The main lesson being, unless it's necessary to the operation being performed ( and here it is not ) then you should not be using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in an aggregation pipeline. It might *look* easier to understand, but your code is actually hurting the system it's running on by including it.

---

### Alternate Client Approach

Note also that if you don't actually need these results for any *further* aggregation processing, then it's probably a lot cleaner to code in the client as each document is processed.

For example, here's a plain JavaScript version for the shell:

```
db.collection.find().map(({ _id, coord }) =>
  (({ coordinates }) =>
    ({
      _id,
      coord,
      ...(m => 
        ({
          minX: Math.min(...m.map(({ x }) => x)),
          minY: Math.min(...m.map(({ y }) => y)),
          maxX: Math.max(...m.map(({ x }) => x)),
          maxY: Math.max(...m.map(({ y }) => y))
        })
      )(
        ((c) => c.reduce((o,e) => [ ...o, ...e ],[]).map(([x,y]) => ({ x, y })) )(coordinates)
      )
  })
  )(coord)
)
```

That has exactly the same output and is not nearly as unwieldy as the BSON operator statements required for an aggregation pipeline.